# show the bean proprty value in jsp page

Tags: jsp

what is the way to shoe the value in jsp page on browser..
 i tried some code  here

```
enter code here
<table class="data-table-list" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<col width="50%"/>
<col width="50%"/>

<tbody>
     <tr>
     <td class="label">
     <fmt:message key="label.bodyLanguage"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
     </td>
     <td class="data">
     <c:out value="${bean.bodyLanguageScore}"/>
     </td>

     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<%@page import="Your Bean Path" %>
<jsp:useBean id="formHandler" class="Your Bean Path" scope="request">
    <jsp:setProperty name="formHandler" property="*"/>
</jsp:useBean> 
        <table class="data-table-list" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" 
                cellspacing="0">
          <col width="50%"/>
          <col width="50%"/>

<tbody>
     <tr>
     <td class="label">
     <fmt:message key="label.bodyLanguage"/><fmt:message key="label.postfix"/>
     </td>
     <td class="data">
            <%=bean.bodyLanguageScore%>
     </td>
         </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: class="YourBeanClass" what i have to insert.. i inserted my Bean name but getting error   Undefined type: 
  YourBeanClass -Prabhakar Manthena

Comment: You need to import the bean in to your jsp. and give the exact path your class

Comment: if your been under package test, bean name MyBean then give test.MyBean

Comment: still it coming same error.. i gave test.Bean and entire path.bean both the cases its coming same error - Prabhakar Manthena

Comment: past your bean code and complete jsp code in the question.. then i can tell you the exact solution.

Comment: public class AsessmentBean extends BaseBean
{
 private Integer bodyLanguageScore;    public Integer getBodyLanguageScore() {
  return bodyLanguageScore;
 }
 public void setBodyLanguageScore(Integer bodyLanguageScore) {
  this.bodyLanguageScore = bodyLanguageScore;
 } } this is my bean and jsp page which was posted

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42645/discussion-between-prabhakar-manthena-and-user51188)

Comment: create a  package bean and move the AsessmentBean into bean package.  then import path will be "bean.AsessmentBean" and  class will be the same. try and let me know if you stuck up with any thing..